# Application signing - changes to APK

Tags: android, hash, certificate, apk, rsa

I have been playing a bit with android APK signing and I'd like to ask few further questions.

I know there is MANIFEST.MF which containes SHA-1 hashes of all files in APK. I know there is CERT.SF that contains hash of manifest and hashes of all manifest entries. And then there is CERT.RSA which contains RSA certificate from keystore used to sign the APK.

I have been able to reproduce contents of MANIFEST.MF and CERT.SF, but I can't find how CERT.RSA is "connected" to those files.

What I mean is: If I change APK contents (f.e. replace app icon), then of course, during install, I get exception saying that hash in MANIFEST and real hash are different. But when I update hashes in MANIFEST and CERT, so that they are correct, I still get Invalid Certificate Exception during install. But this time on the very first resource file in apk.

So how does Android know that I changed something in the apk even when I updated hashes? I see this is somehow related to CERT.RSA, but I struggle to find out how it really works.

EDIT, to put it more clearly: What all, except things mentioned above, has to match so that Android would consider some APK valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I did some more research and stumbled upon this great talk from BlackHat Conference:
http://youtu.be/ExX9_BN9XL8

It's about the Andorid Master Key exploit, which is closely related to APK signing. Although I'd still appreciate deeper explanation of some cryptographical processes under the hood of all this, this talk is a great start. I definitely recommend it for anyone interested in this topic.
(If you know any related talks/texts, please share them as comment or answer)

If I find anything more thorough, I'll add it here later for future generations :)
Until then, real answer is: read the source code...